# Kivy crushes in raspberry pi 3 with an eleduino capacitive touchscreen

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

i have done the following steps:
1. Installed kivy properly, everything works 
2. Connected an eleduino capacitive touchscreen
3. Changed the ~/.kivy/config.ini file. I changed the [input] part:

```
    test = mtdev,/dev/input/event3
```

**** touch works for around 90 seconds and then crashes
4. Changed the ~/.kivy/config.ini file. The [input] part:

```
    mouse = mouse
    mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs, provider=mtdev=dev/input/event3
    hid_%(name)s = probesys,provider=hidinput
```

*** the same touch works for a period of time then dies
I have no clue on what could be the problem. I am sure the touch crushes because if i press ctrl+c the application ends. Besides, i have noted that after the 90 seconds the touch still works but in the background, it ignores kivy.